# Delphi Key Code 17 in FormKeyDown

Tags: forms, delphi, keypress, keycode

I have this procedure and I get it's called when I press a key, and something else will happen when Key = 17, how can I know which key is it?

```
procedure TFormPrincipal.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;Shift: TShiftState);
 begin
  if Key = 17 then
    Seventeen:= true;
 end;
```

Comment: Do you know `17` is `VK_CONTROL`? Or do you have a key labelled `17` on your keyboard, and believe this will be triggered by it?

Comment: I received this code as it is, and didn't know 17 was CTRL

Comment: Using some unknown features will lead me first to documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnKeyDown and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TKeyEvent and final to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Virtual_Key_Codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Key" refers to the VirtualKeyCode of the key. 17 equals to VK_CONTROL, either of your CTRL keys. [Check this list](http://cherrytree.at/misc/vk.htm) for reference.